# Typescript: Property 'x' is missing in type '{}' for computed key

Tags: typescript

This piece of Typescript:

```
enum Field {
    age,
    bugs,
}
interface Foo {
    number_age: number;
    number_bugs: number;
}

function makeFoo():Foo {
    let ret = {};
    let i = 0;
    for (let key in Field) {
        ret['number_'+key] = i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

throws this error when compiling:

```
$ tsc test.ts 
test.ts(16,5): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
  Property 'number_age' is missing in type '{}'.
```

But `ret` will definitely have a `number_age` property at runtime.  How do I either trick the compiler into knowing that `number_age` and `number_bugs` will be there or otherwise change my code so that it compiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define that `ret` will be a `Foo` element using the keyword `as`

```
enum Field {
    age,
    bugs,
}
interface Foo {
    number_age: number;
    number_bugs: number;
}

function makeFoo():Foo {
    let ret = {} as Foo;
    let i = 0;
    for (let key in Field) {
        ret['number_'+key] = i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Read the documentation about [type assertions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> Sometimes you’ll end up in a situation where you’ll know more about a
>   value than TypeScript does. Usually this will happen when you know the
>   type of some entity could be more specific than its current type.
>
> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what
>   I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages,
>   but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no
>   runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes
>   that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you
>   need.

Type assertions have two forms. One is the “angle-bracket” syntax:

```
let someValue: any = "this is a string";

let strLength: number = (<string>someValue).length;
```

And the other is the as-syntax:

```
let someValue: any = "this is a string";

let strLength: number = (someValue as string).length;
```

The two samples are equivalent. Using one over the other is mostly a choice of preference; however, when using TypeScript with JSX, only as-style assertions are allowed.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I didn't understand the difference between `let ret:Foo = {};` and `let ret = {} as Foo;` but this answer helps.

Comment: @iffy the former means that `ret` *is* a Foo, while the latter means to treat `ret` as Foo, without taking care of the content at the moment.

The former will give you an error because you do not initialize with the right parameters, while the latter will not consider that.

Comment: Right, and your answer clarified that for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty far off the rails here (you're going to also make `number_0` and `number_1` properties on `Foo`, is this intended?) so it's going to be more work than its worth to "properly" typecheck this code. Just use `any`:

```
function makeFoo():Foo {
    let ret: any = {};
    let i = 0;
    for (let key in Field) {
        ret['number_'+key] = i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that the compiler assumes `ret` is `Foo`-able when returned?  Isn't that a bad assumption (by the compiler)?  I don't understand why this solution works, though it does indeed work.  (And thanks for the heads up about `number_0` and `number_1`)

Answer (score 0):

you should use casting operator <TYPE>

```
enum Field {
    age,
    bugs,
}
interface Foo {
    number_age: number;
    number_bugs: number;
}

function makeFoo():Foo {
    let ret = {};
    let i = 0;
    for (let key in Field) {
        ret['number_'+key] = i++;
    }
    return <Foo>ret; // Here 
}
```

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh yes it does (for me with TypeScript 2.3.2)